# How to call Octave/Matlab script from C++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu, octave

I have a bunch of related Octave/Matlab files out of which one of them contains a function that I need to call and use that result in a C++ program that I am writing on Ubuntu. I have Octave installed on this system so I'll be using Octave specific solutions to this problem.

I have installed the octave header file packages. I seem to get an error when writing this simple code.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  octave_main(argc, (char**)argv, true);
  ColumnVector sz(2);
  sz(0) = 10; 
  sz(1) = 12; 
  octave_value_list functionArguments = octave_value(sz);
  do_octave_atexit();
  return 0;
}
```

The compilation command is

```
g++ -L /usr/lib/octave/3.2.4 -I /usr/lib/octave-3.2.4 -loctinterp -loctave -loctave salone.cpp
```

The error that I get is

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/octave-3.2.4/liboctinterp.so: undefined reference to symbol 'Array<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~Array()'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'Array<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::~Array()' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/octave-3.2.4/liboctave.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/octave-3.2.4/liboctave.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could someone please explain how to solve this? I have seen some example but they are about making a standalone problem, which does not seem to be what I am looking for. I just have a complicated Octave script which I want to use with a C++ program.

So, apart from solving this error, how do I do that? I could not find any documentation which was clear enough to help me do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess: sometimes the order of libraries matters. Try changing the occurence of `-loctinterp` and `-loctave` and remove the duplicate of `-loctave`. Another hint: creating a minimal example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could help others to reproduce the error.

Comment: And I think there should be no whitespace between `-L` and the path as well as between `-I` and the path, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC17